# Angular dynamically populate table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically populate a table using the following code:

**teams.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TeamService } from 'src/app/services/team.service';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-teams',
  templateUrl: './teams.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teams.component.scss']
})
export class TeamsComponent implements OnInit {
  public teams : any; 

  tableCols = ['id', 'name'];

  constructor(private teamService : TeamService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.teamService.getTeams().pipe(first()).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.teams = data.results
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.error)
      }
    ) 
  }

}
```

**teams.component.html**

```
<app-table [tableData]="teams" [tableColumns]="tableCols"></app-table>
```

**table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  tableDataSrc: any;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-input-rename
  @Input('tableColumns') tableCols: string[];
  @Input() tableData: {}[] = [];

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableDataSrc = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    this.tableDataSrc.sort = this.sort;
    this.tableDataSrc.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

}
```

**table.component.html**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSrc" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of tableCols">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{ col }}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{ col | titlecase }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let profile">{{ profile }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableCols"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableCols"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

A 'team' object looks like the following:

`{'id': 9, 'name': 'FC Barcelona'}` and the `teams` variable is a list of these objects.

When I navigate to the teams page the table is rendered and stays empty, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could be that ngOnInit in table.component is called before the getTeams() TeamsComponent in finishes?

Try to have another method that has input of the info and not ngOnInit.

Add console.log to see the life cycle hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing this part in `table.component.ts`

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableDataSrc = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    this.tableDataSrc.sort = this.sort;
    this.tableDataSrc.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

with this

```js
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      if(changes.tableData.currentValue) {
          this.tableDataSrc = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
          this.tableDataSrc.sort = this.sort;
          this.tableDataSrc.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
  }
```

The problem is `teams` field in `TeamsComponent` gets initialized after (due to async operation) `TableComponent`s OnInit phase. If you change `ngOnInit` with `ngOnChanges` whenever `teams` field changes `TableComponent` becomes aware of it.

Further reading: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#using-change-detection-hooks